# How to calculate the Ecological footprint

Tags: environmental-protection, carbon

I'm looking for a algorithm or a formula to calculate the ecological footprint of one person who is using any kind of vehicle (car, public transit...).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in sustainability.stackexchange.com and it has already been answered there: http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-i-estimate-my-personal-ecological-footprint